# Saved JSON file is overwritten

Tags: json, vue.js, electron

I want to save user input to a JSON for that, let's say, I have the following code:

```
// saves data in to an object
saveData() {
  let summaryValues = {
    what: this.what.txt,
    how: this.how.txt,
    checkedValue: this.checked
  };
  this.savedValueArr.push(summaryValues);
},
 //uses the array with the pushed object to append the JSON
saveAsJson() {
  const fs = require("fs");

 var content = JSON.stringify(this.savedValueArr);
  fs.appendFile("testFile.json", content, err => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    alert("File has been saved");
    this.what.txt = "";
    this.how.txt = "";
    this.checked = "";
  });
},
 // reads JSON and pushs it to a variable
read() {
  const fs = require("fs");

  fs.readFile("testFile.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
      return;
    }

    // push parsed data back in to an array
    let dataParse = JSON.parse(data);
    this.test.push(dataParse);

  });

}
```

read() and saveAsJson() are both click events the saveAsJson saves the data on click in the testFile.json, the read() reads the testFile.json on click and 
my first problem now is that my JSON looks like this after I filled it with two arrays

`[{"what":"test2","how":"test2","checkedValue":2},{"what":"test1","how":"test1","checkedValue":1}][{"what":"test2","how":"test2","checkedValue":2}]`

my second problem is, if I close the app then reopen it and click first on the button that has the read function (to load in the data) and then fill out the fields and click on the button that has the saveAsJson function bound to it my JSON overwrites the old saved data and only holds the new one. Which I dont want to happen.

I'm using electron with vue.js if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the variable in the read function

```
read() {
  const fs = require("fs");

  fs.readFile("testFile.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
    alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
    return;
}

// push parsed data back in to an array
let dataParse = JSON.parse(data);
// CHANGED
this.savedValueArr.push(dataParse);

});
```